# Show duplicate of a record when last name matches in a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling with writing this query and I am a little stumped.

Desired output:

```
ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME PRODUCTIONUNIT
1   fname1    lname2          PU1
2   fname4    lname2           PU1
3   fname5    lnamex          PU2
4   fname7    lnamey           PU2
5   fname8    lname2          PU3
```

I want to display the records whenever the last names are the same within a PRODUCTIONUNIT

This is how far I have gotten but i am not getting the results

```
    SELECT * 
FROM   contactversion__c 
WHERE  id IN(SELECT id 
               FROM   contactversion__c 
               GROUP  BY productionunit 
                         lastname 
               HAVING Count(DISTINCT lastname > 1)) 
ORDER  BY c.`name`, 
          b.`name`;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd0fd0/1

Comment: Sample data leading to the desired results would help.  Similarly, it would be good to know how your query doesn't work -- at least one problem is all the extra columns in it.

Comment: Copy to the psychic forum, or see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I have tried to minimize the table content and load is sqlfiddle hopefully if someone would be so kind to take a look at it agian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyones help I was able to figure it out using a inner join and matching with productionunit and lastname. The query below got me the desired results using SQLFiddle

```
SELECT
        a.id,
        a.firstname,
        a.lastname,
        a.productionunit
    FROM contactversion a
    JOIN (SELECT
            productionunit ,lastname ,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM contactversion 
    GROUP BY productionunit, lastname
     HAVING count(*)>1 ) b
     ON a.lastname = b.lastname and a.productionunit=b.productionunit
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35701aa/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that one problem lies in the part

```sql
GROUP  BY production_unit__c, last_name__c 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT last_name__c > 1)
```

This for two reasons:

1. The closing bracket should be before `> 1`, right?.
2. A `Count(DISTINCT last_name__c)` together with a `group by
   production_unit_c,last_name_c` including `last_name_c` in the group
   by always yields '1', right?

So replacing this part with the following should do the job:

```
GROUP  BY production_unit__c
HAVING Count(DISTINCT last_name__c) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks but by changing this the query yields no results. The table has 26k records I am positive there are some matches within a pu

Comment: Have you tried to run `SELECT id FROM contactversion__c GROUP BY production_unit__c HAVING Count(DISTINCT last_name__c) > 1` on it's own? Does it give you any results?

Comment: No the subquery itself has no results

Comment: ups - I missed that id is not part of the group by, which is actually not allowed. Need some time...

Comment: please try `select c2.id from contactversion__c c2, contactversion__c c3 where c2.id <> c3.id and c2. production_unit__c = c3. production_unit__c and c2. last_name__c = c3. last_name__c`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be returning results when I run the query by itself. I am adding it as a subquery in the where clause and it's taking quite some time. I'll update once I get results. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This should result in a correct result as far as i interpret you question/ db structure.

```
 SELECT     `c`.`id` AS Id, 
            `c`.`first_name__c` AS FirstName, 
            `c`.`last_name__c` AS LastName, 
            `r`.`name` AS RecordType, 
            `p`.`name` AS ProductionUnitName
FROM        contactversion__c  
INNER JOIN  recordtype r ON c.recordtypeid = r.id 
INNER JOIN  production_unit__c p ON c.production_unit__c = p.id 
WHERE  EXISTS( 
    SELECT      TRUE
    FROM        contactversion__c 
    WHERE       contactversion__c.production_unit__c = c.production_unit__c
        AND     contactversion__c.last_name__c = c.last_name__c
        AND     contactversion__c.id != c.id
    LIMIT       1
)
ORDER  BY `RecordType`, `ProductionUnitName`
```